# JSF Spring injection via XML or code

Tags: java, spring, jsf, dependency-injection

I've inherited some JSF Spring code, and can see instead of injecting the Spring beans via the `faces-config.xml` as

```
<managed-bean>
```

the team have done it in the code as

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELResolver elResolver = facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver();
    MyClass myBean = (MyClass) elResolver.getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null,ApplicationConstants.MY_BEAN_NAME);
```

I would prefer doing this in the xml - **is there any advantage of that or is it no big deal at all?**

Versions are JSF 1.2 and Spring 3

Comment: The code you have shown is placed where exactly?

Comment: @Jigar: inside a managed bean class as instance variables. Managed bean has session scope

Comment: I would prefer XML or annotation (jsf 2.0 style)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps they just don't like XML?

Personally, I'd use annotation-based dependency injection wherever possible, instead of XML configuration or code.

However, there is one case where the code-based approach is the only one that works: when you have a managed bean with larger scope (e.g. session or even application) and it one of its actions need access to a managed bean with smaller scope (e.g. request).

Comment: Didn't know that. Here both are session scope.

Comment: are you referring to `@Autowired` annotation?

Comment: @JoseK: No, I was talking about about @ManagedProperty, but now I see that you're using JSF 1.2, and those annotations were only introduced in JSF 2. In that case, I agree with you that XML configuration would be preferable.